# Jsoup catchdata appear unknowhost exception ,and can`t ping the website ,but my web browser can visit

Tags: jsoup, user-agent, ping, unknown-host

Jsoup catch data appear unknowhost exception ,and can`t  ping the website ,but my web browser can visit

I try change the userAgent,but it doesn`t work!
Here are the userAgent before:

***Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36***

Here the my browser userAgent which can visit:

***Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36***

Although I change the userAgent,but it remains the unknowhost exception !

Here is my code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(source+"/blacklist/"+y+"_m0_p"+p) //     
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")  //
                    .timeout(5000 * tryCount) //
                    .get();
```

Comment: can you share the URL which you are trying to reach? Also please post the Java code that you use to access the site. What is the StackTrace?

Comment: doc = Jsoup.connect(source+"/blacklist/"+y+"_m0_p"+p)
         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")
         .timeout(5000 * tryCount)
         .get();  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~the web  site :http://www.ppdai.com/blacklist/2014

Answer (score 0):

> but my web browser can visit

Check if your browser uses a proxy. If so, tell Jsoup to use the same proxy:

```
String host = "..."; // Proxy host
String port = "..."; // Proxy port

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port);

System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port);

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(source+"/blacklist/"+y+"_m0_p"+p) //     
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")  //
                    .timeout(5000 * tryCount) //
                    .get();
```